# MySQL workbench ALTER USER statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MySQL and when I type in my password for setting up a new connection it comes back with:

> You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

I have read up about this (ie. type in:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('your_new_password') 
       WHERE User='root';
```

but I am new to technology in general, so I'm not sure where it means to type this in. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed a new MySQL server with standard users or maybe it's done by your system admin (if you have one): what seems to happen here is that your password is set to be expired and you first have to set a new one before you can do anything. MySQL Workbench usually asks you for a new password if that is the case on login. I'm not sure what happens when you refuse to do so.

If you cannot change the password as part of expiration recovery you will need another user with rights to update users. Login to MySQL with this other user and then update the password as explained in your question. Make sure you don't kill the root password or you will have extra work to recover it.

If you don't want/can use MySQL Workbench for your MySQL work you can always go back to the terminal. First start the mysql client and then run the sql commands in that (assuming here a server on the local box, listening on default port 3306):

```
Mikes-iMac:~ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P3306  -p 
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 112
Server version: 8.0.1-dmr-enterprise-commercial-advanced MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

About user management in MySQL Workbench. When you open a connection (which requires a valid user with the proper rights, like the default root user) you can switch to the management tab and there to the "Users and Privileges" page. Here you can assign privileges, change passwords, create and delete users etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SET PASSWORD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html):

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

or for a particular user, say abcuser:

```
SET PASSWORD for 'abcuser'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

Comment: but where do you type this?

Comment: this is now happening when I type SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD ('apple');  -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @Merialc - You need to run this on MySQL prompt.. not UNIX prompt.

Comment: i really am a beginner - not familiar with using mysql prompt or unix prompt, am on a mac if that helps...